# Headless Drupal 8 - cookie authentication

Tags: 8, cookies

I am successfully using a headless Drupal 8 setup that I am querying through Drupal 8 core REST API with basic auth from jQuery AJAX. Now I need to get closer to production conditions, so I started trying to use cookie-based authentication. Problem is that the exact same query that successfully POSTed content using basic auth now returns an HTTP 403.

Is there any working example of a POST request to create an article with cookie authentication? Am I missing something?

I have a fresh Drupal 8.3.1 install with REST UI, Serialization and HAL modules enabled. The REST endpoints are configured through REST UI. The */node/{node}* endpoint is set up to allow all requests in all formats with cookie auth. Taxonomy and user endpoints are configured likewise.
The queries (POST & GET) to REST API are made from AJAX calls from jQuery. These queries work fine with basic auth. This is a query example.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'my_drupal/entity/node?_format=hal_json&foo=bar,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/hal+json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken, // I got that token by first GETting my_drupal/rest/session/token
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.credentials)
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(node),
      success: function (node) {
         // success logic here
      }
    });
```

Please note that I already tried removing the *Authorization* header with no luck.

Monitoring HTTP requests, I do see the Drupal authentication cookie being sent along with my POST request.

Comment: Any other errors in your browser JS console?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Since the latest Drupal update, the 403 error comes with a message saying "Authentication method not allowed on this route". Which IMHO is wrong.

Comment: Questions aren't for a back-and-forth with the users who answer them, which means they cannot be update to say that what suggested from an answer doesn't help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asking to recommend or suggest books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like maybe you are not successfully retrieving the CSRF token. The CSRF token can be retrieved from `/rest/session/token`.

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/3-post-for-creating-content-entities for examples on POSTing to core entity endpoints.

Comment: Woops, my bad. Indeed I get the CSRF token at this URL (`/rest/session/token`), I made a mistake writing my comment. I edited my first post to make it clearer. Note that the code I show in this first post does work with basic auth.

Answer (score 4):

> the 403 error comes with a message saying "Authentication method not
>   allowed on this route"

OK, so it appears that route may not support the cookie authentication method, by default.

For example, https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21rest%21config%21optional%21rest.resource.entity.node.yml/8.2.x > View source

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - basic_auth
    - hal
    - node
id: entity.node
plugin_id: 'entity:node'
granularity: resource
configuration:
  methods:
    - GET
    - POST
    - PATCH
    - DELETE
  formats:
    - hal_json
  authentication:
    - basic_auth
```

You will need to extend or alter the node resource POST config in *rest.resource.entity.node.yml* to ensure the "cookie" method is enabled in `supported_auth`

e.g: Configure in admin UI

[image: node supported_auth]

More info: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview > "Drupal 8.2 & Later"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the documented answer! I am unable to try that today, but will do tomorrow. The weird thing is that REST UI *does* show me the `cookie` checkbox for all methods of the `/node/{node}` route (and of course I ticked them), so I assumed it was available. But I will try to figure out what's happening in the `yml` files.

Comment: Just tried following your instructions, please see Edit² in my initial post.